# Profiling a python 3.6 module from the command line

Tags: python, profiling, python-3.6, cprofile

I have a python project where I execute the app as a module using the `-m` flag. So something like:

```
python -m apps.validate -i input.mp4
```

Now, I want to profile it using the command line. So the inline examples suggest invoking cProfile itself a module. However, I cannot do something like:

```
python -m cProfile apps.validate -i input.mp4
```

However, this results in the error "No such file or directory". I cannot just go to the `apps` directory and launch `validate.py` due to relative imports.

Is there a way to profile a module on the command line?

Comment: There's a "New in version 3.7" note in the `cProfile` [online documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#instant-user-s-manual) that says a `-m` option was added to `cProfile` in that version. This is in addition to the Python interpreter's own `-m` option, This means that something like `python -m cProfile -m apps.validate -i input.mp4` ought to work (if you're using Python 3.7+).

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, my stuff needs python 3.6 as some of the other libraries are not working with 3.7. I guess I will need to use it in code.

Comment: You could look at the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/profile.py) for  `profile` (and `cProfile`) and see how support for the new `-m` option was added. It might even be possible to use that version of it with an earlier version of the Python interpreter (depending on what other changes were made).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of running cProfile in shell, maybe you can use cProfile in your python script by adding some code in apps.validate or creating a new script and import apps.validate like this. Maybe some typo below :)

```
import cProfile
import sys

def run_validate(args): 
    # run your apps.validate code with shell arguments args here
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pr = cProfile.Profile()
    pr.enable()
    run_validate(*sys.argv)
    pr.disable()
    pr.print_stats()
```

then just run the original script: python -m apps.validate -i input.mp4

Comment: pr.dump_stats(filename) would save it to a file.